# Invoke/execute command with an unknown number of parameters, in PowerShell

Tags: command-line, powershell, parameters

Want to execute `Invoke-Expression` with parameters which can vary depending on the input

Having a problem with `$MyArgs` logic. It should contain only entered parameters

Input (example):

```
./foo.ps1 -Name aa -Server bb -Datastore cc
```

Output:

```
Get-VM -Name aa -Server bb -Datastore cc
```

Code:

```
    [cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Get-VM')]
    Param(
        #Common params
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Get-VM')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Get-Datastore')]
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [String]$Name,     

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Get-VM')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Get-Datastore')]
        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [String]$Server,

        #Get-VM params
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Get-VM')]
        [String]$Datastore,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Get-VM')]
        .
        .
        .

        #Get-Datastore params
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Get-Datastore')]
        [String]$Datacenter,        
        .
        .
        .
    )

Invoke-Expression -Command "$PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName $MyArgs" \\ <--- here is my problem
```

Comment: I could use `Command`, but the execution will be on localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're going to use three PowerShell features:

- The call operator, `&`, invokes a command whose name can be specified by an expression. Unlike `Invoke-Expression`, it can handle bound parameters without stringifying everything.
- The `$PSBoundParameters` variable is a hashtable of the parameters specified to the current cmdlet and their values.
- [Splatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) is like the reverse of `$PSBoundParameters`: it uses a hashtable as the bound parameters to a cmdlet.

Putting it all together, we replace your `Invoke-Expression` invocation with this, calling a cmdlet whose name is the parameter set name and passing it all the function's parameters:

```
& $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName @PSBoundParameters
```

Comment: Cool, works as expected, simplicity is genius :) Just learning how to use parameters in PowerShell, so really appreciate for the extra information and explanation